# Changing date and time position on the lock screen - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I'm trying to move the position of time/date/password field in the lock screen. (currently they are on the center).

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206001/changing-date-and-time-position-on-the-lock-screen-ubuntu-18-04) explained how to do it for `18.04`, but on `20.04` the mentionned method does not work anymore.

I think the relevant file is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`
and the relevantz css field is

```
.unlock-dialog-clock {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  spacing: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 2.5em; }
```

I tried messing with those value, and refreshing gnome via `alt+F2`, write `rt`, then `enter`, without any sucess.
Any idea ?

Comment: This may be a dupe of https://askubuntu.com/a/1238670/32664. @nOtis, have you tried this solution?

Comment: yes I did, it did not work as I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Solved, it turns out gnome CSS are compiled and one can't just edit them inplace.
One needs to decompile the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`, edit the `.css` (`unlock-dialog-clock` is indeed the correct field) with the desired change, recompile to gresource, then put it back at the correct location.
then one needs to refresh gnome to see changes  (reboot, or faster : `alt + F2`, then write `rt` then `enter`)

To easily decompile/recompile `.gresource` file, this repo was super usefull:
https://github.com/zegheim/Pop-modified